# The use of "consistent with".

Tags: article-writing

This is a simple question about writing but I'm a little bit confused now about the logic in using "consistent with".
The context is as follows:

We first derive a formula for a special case, say, for $i=2$.
Later we derive a formula for general cases, say, for $i=3,4,5...$,
which is actually also true for $i=2$.
Shall we say "**the formula for $i=2$ is consistent with the general formula**"
or
 "**the general formula is consistent with the special case($i=2$) before**" ?

Reference to some existing texts would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have removed the 'logic' tag; this question is not related to the field of mathematical logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in this case you should say that the case of i=2 is consistent with the general formula. The reason why is because you are taking note of a particular example, that holds true. So because it holds true, this is consistent with your theorem that it holds for i=1,2,3.. etc